# Can Spring LdapTemplate stream results?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, java-stream, spring-ldap

I am trying to query an active directory for ALL person objects. There are over `700,000` results which are way too many to read into a `List`. My current solution is using paging to get all of the results but I would much rather use the Java-8 Stream-API to get them instead. Unfortunately, I have not found any methods on `LdapTemplate` that return a `Stream` object.

I know that this can return all of the results:

```java
public List<LdapPerson> findAll() {
        return ldapTemplate.search("","(objectClass=person)", mapper);
    }
```

but what I'm looking for is something that can return:

```java
public Stream<LdapPerson> findAll(){
   return ldaptemplate.?????????;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `return ldapTemplate.search("","(objectClass=person)", mapper).stream()` unless you're looking for the datastore to return the stream.

Answer (score 1):

No, the [`LdapTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#search-org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQuery-org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper-) doesn't provide a method that *directly* returns a `Stream<T>` from a searched elements. However, since the method, [`LdapTemplate::search`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html#search-org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQuery-org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper-) returns a `List<T>`, then you can use a characteristics of *any* `Collection<T>` that is convertible to `Stream<T>` using a simple call of [`collection.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) method:

```
public Stream<LdapPerson> findAll() {
    return ldapTemplate.search("", "(objectClass=person)", mapper).stream();
}
```

Comment: But won't that still try to pull in all 700,000+ data elements before streaming? I'm really looking for a way to stream them directly from the AD store.